# jackson to sort the response by using the field name alone

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, jackson

I have several pojo classes.
The used the Jackson `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation to omit the class name but the properties are not sorting how I expect.

For Example:

```
class a {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    B b;
    int c;
    //getters and setters
}

class B {
    int a;
    int d;
    // getters and setters
}
```

My actual response is:

```
{
c:1
a:2
d:2
}
```

But my expected response is:

```
{
a:2
c:1
d:2
}
```

How can make it so that the fields in the response are sorted by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because Jackson groups the serialization of all properties of the unwrapped object together.  The `@JsonPropertyOrder` annotation can't override this behavior because it [works on the unwrapped field](https://gist.github.com/cheseaux/a2bf1b27680ff969c354) and not the field's properties.  As a workaround, you can serialize the object to an intermediate `Map`, sort it yourself, and then serialize it to JSON as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map map = objectMapper.convertValue(new a(), Map.class);
SortedMap sortedMap = new TreeMap(map);
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(sortedMap));
```

Comment: i am using spring java project can please tell how to configure this using Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder

Comment: I don't know of a clean way to do that.